# How to update ordering of items inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like below

```
 ORIGINAL ARRAY:   [{id:100, order: 1}, {id:101, order:2}, {id:102,order:3}, {id:103,order:4}, {id:104,order:5}]
```

If I move the first element to the last, I want the resulting array should look like this

```
[{id:101, order:1}, {id:102,order:2}, {id:103,order:3}, {id:104,order:4}, {id:100, order: 5}]
```

If I move the second last element to the first, the resulting array should look like this

```
[{id:103,order:1}, {id:100, order: 2}, {id:101, order:3}, {id:102,order:4}, {id:104,order:5}]
```

How can I do these kind of ordering updates inside objects?

I am using splice method to remove and insert object in the correct index

```
list.remove(item); //uses knockoutjs remove() method
list.splice(position, 0, item);
```

But stuck at updating ordering part. Can someone help.

Comment: Why do you even have these redundant `order` properties that you have to manually keep synchronized with the array's *actual* order? Why not just have an array of ID values?

Comment: I recommend that you remove html as well, The only two tags needed are Javascript and Arrays as those are the only two relevant things here. (There is no HTML code involved therefor tag isn't required) @SarathSNair

Comment: In database side we are maintaining a column for `order`, which is used for other purposes. Whenever user changes the original array and update db, it should be saved there. So we are using an `order` key

Comment: @NaruS Done. Removed `html` tag also

Comment: Why users down-voting this question? Is it unclear? I didn't understand.

Comment: I am not to sure @SarathSNair There is no reason for the down-votes at all. The only reason I could have seen was the python mistag the mistag with html is understandable though.